# Adding a column which uses other column fields as operands for operation like addition and percentage calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sp_TotalMarks]
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT Student_Id, Stu_Name, Maths, English, Hindi,
           (Maths + English + Hindi) AS 'Total',
            CAST(CAST((Maths + English + Hindi) AS NUMERIC(8,2)) / 300 * 100 AS NUMERIC(8,2)) AS 'Percentage'
    FROM tbl_Marks

END
```

This is the procedure which I am using to display percentage. 
If there are 100 students in a class and I want to display the percentage of each one of them then the SP which dynamically calculates the %age and returns the answer , will be time consuming. Earlier I was trying to add a column of percentage in tbl_Marks itself.Is it possible to implement trigger in the store procedure which is called on 'INSERT' or 'UPDATE' operation on the tbl_Marks. I have never used trigger actually. If you could explain me the solution of this problem with a query It would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 100 rows in a table is a very small number and it is hard to imagine how any routine query could be "time-consuming".  If you want to optimize a query, please edit your question and include the query in the edit.

Comment: you can add a calculated column marked persistent in your table tbl_Marks.. it should resolve the issue.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I don't know how to put the code in correct way on this website. I have edited my question.

Comment: @Deepshikha I didn't get you . Can you explain it more clearly. You mean I can add this cal column in my table. I don't want to call this procedure again and again when ever I need to view the details.

Comment: check now.. hope this servers the purpose!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `computed column` can use data from other columns of the table to calculate a value for the column to which it belongs.Also a `computed column` is a virtual column that is not physically stored in the table, unless the column is marked PERSISTED.

So alter your table definition as:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_Marks ADD total AS (Maths + English + Hindi) PERSISTED;
ALTER TABLE tbl_Marks ADD Percentage AS CAST(CAST((Maths + English + Hindi) AS NUMERIC(8,2)) / 300 * 100 AS NUMERIC(8,2)) PERSISTED;
```

This will add two columns to the table which will reflect the computed values on each update or insert.

You can check the [DEMO here](http://rextester.com/IQW16523). Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Yes That's what I wanted to implement. Plus I liked this website rextester. Thanks a ton !